# В чем разница между двумя лямбдами

Tags: c++, lambda

В чём разница между

```
[&](){x;}
```

и

```
[&x](){x;}
```

?

Comment: Например, если `x` это макрос, то разница может быть как угодно большая :)

Comment: @VladD Вопрос в том, есть ли разница между тем, что лямбда сразу знает захватываемые переменные или из {} их извлекает

Comment: @dfa Ну, касательно вашего вопроса, то разница в том, что во втором случае вы явно ограничиваете список переменных, видимых в области объявления функции (в контексте которой объявлена лямбда), которые вы можете захватывать (например, чтобы жестко ограничить себя от использования лишнего внутри лямбды), а в первом случае автоматически выхватятся все используемые внутри лямбды переменные из области объявления функции.

Comment: @StateItPrimitive ну это понятно, а вот с точки зрения захвата "явно" и "неявно". мб когда само определяется это медленней работает?

Comment: @dfa Я предполагаю, что список параметров захвата лямбы определяется в момент компиляции (т.е. при трансляции кода в объектные файлы), т.е. на runtime никак влиять не может.

Comment: Т.е. существует вероятность, что проект будет компилироваться на n-ую долю секунды дольше (где _n_ довольно большое число), но поверьте, при современных процессорах это абсолютно не критично.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В таком конкретном варианте - по сути ничем. Просто в первом случае происходит захват по ссылке всех переменных, а во втором - конкретной. Но так как в теле ничего, кроме `x`, не используется, то разницы никакой. Особенно при оптимизации кода :) - они будут, скорее всего, просто убраны совсем.

VC++ 2015 именно так и поступил - выкинул вообще при оптимизации, а без оной сгенерировал два абсолютно одинаковых кода.